Rust generic lifetime elision issue
I am trying to a implement generic observable collections for use with a UI framework I'm writing. I'm currently having an issue with lifetimes not being elidable in generics.
For brevity the following Callback and Event types not the full event framework but the issue should still be highlighted.
type Callback<Args> = Arc<dyn Fn(&Args)>;

struct Event<Args> {
    handlers: Vec<Callback<Args>>,
}

struct OnChangedArgs<'a, T> {
    items: std::slice::Iter<'a, T>,
}

struct ObservableList<T> {
    items: Vec<T>,
    on_changed: Event<OnChangedArgs<'_, T>>,
                                // ^^^^^ can't elid lifetime
}

I can resolve my issue by writing my event system in a non generic manner but that would may code duplication highly annoying.
struct OnChangedArgs<'a, T> {
    items: std::slice::Iter<'a, T>,
}

pub type OnChangedCallback<T> = Arc<dyn Fn(&OnChangedArgs<T>)>;
                                                     // ^^^^^ lifetime elided

struct OnChangedEvent<T> {
    handlers: Vec<OnChangedCallback<T>>,
}

struct ObservableList<T> {
    items: Vec<T>,
    on_changed: OnChangedEvent<T>,
                               
}

Am I dumb or does this seem to be an annoyance with the Rust type system???
It just seems like the type system should be able to see through Event to see that it can elid the lifetime. That way you don't have to unnecessarily bubble the lifetime up so that you have to deal with it higher up in another struct.

Why do you think the lifetime is unnecessary? I can't understand. Also, it's likely you want a higher-ranked lifetime, not a concrete one (but I can't tell just from this code).

@ChayimFriedman When you explicitly write Arc<dyn Fn(&OnChangedArgs<T>)> it automatically elids the lifetime to the lifetime of when the Fn gets called. In the case of the generic type Callback<Args> = Arc<dyn Fn(&Args)>;    struct Event<Args> { handler : Callback<Args>} the code Event<OnChangedArgs<T>> is invalid because it's missing the lifetime parameter. If the elider could see through Event<Args> it would see that handler would be equivalent to Arc<dyn Fn(&OnChangedArgs<T>)> and could elid accordingly.

This "elision" is called a higher-ranked lifetime, and you can do the same, but it will be rather convoluted.

@ChayimFriedman Thanks! I've seen snippets of that but wasn't sure what it was called. As of right now I've just defaulted to using 'static and then using transmute to get back to the proper lifetimes but hopefully I can switch to higher-ranked lifetimes whenever I can figure that out.

I don't know if you will like that (or if it is a good idea anyway), but there is a way to make the lifetime higher-ranked (therefore eliding it), by using Generic Associated Types:
use std::sync::Arc;

type Callback<Args> = Arc<dyn Fn(&<Args as EventArgs>::Gatified<'_>)>;

trait EventArgs {
    type Gatified<'a>;
}

struct Event<Args: EventArgs> {
    handlers: Vec<Callback<Args>>,
}

impl<Args: EventArgs> Event<Args> {
    fn trigger(&self, args: &Args::Gatified<'_>) {
        for handler in &self.handlers {
            handler(args);
        }
    }
}

struct OnChangedArgs<'a, T> {
    items: std::slice::Iter<'a, T>,
}

impl<T: 'static> EventArgs for OnChangedArgs<'static, T> {
    type Gatified<'a> = OnChangedArgs<'a, T>;
}

struct ObservableList<T: 'static> {
    items: Vec<T>,
    on_changed: Event<OnChangedArgs<'static, T>>,
}

impl<T: 'static> ObservableList<T> {
    fn notify(&self) {
        self.on_changed.trigger(&OnChangedArgs {
            items: self.items.iter(),
        });
    }
}

OnChangedArgs<'static> serves as a marker type (it could also be a different type) that enables the GATification of any OnChangedArgs.

Thank you! I just took another look at it using this approach. I was able to  completely eliminate all use of 'static by using two layers of GAT. One for the event args and one so that different observable collections can use different iterators to notify the event.

You can't elide the lifetime in that context because there is nowhere from which a lifetime can be inferred. Simply add a named lifetime parameter to the defining type:
struct ObservableList<'a, T> {
    items: Vec<T>,
    on_changed: Event<OnChangedArgs<'a, T>>,
}

This is a good thing, because it makes it explicit that ObservableList contains a borrow.

The problem with that is that it unnecessarily bubbles an uneeded lifetime up another level. Event doesn't actually borrow anything. The borrow of OnChangedArgs only occurs when its eventually passed-by-reference as an argument to the callbacks.

@JacobGreen If it doesn't borrow anything then you can use OnChangedArgs<'static, T>. However, note there is a big difference between "borrowing an OnChangedArgs" and "OnChangedArgs borrowing something." If OnChangedArgs has a lifetime parameter, then the latter is true, but you are talking about the former.
